# How to save dictionary data in list ? and return that list in Python?

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

I have a json file i need to retrieve data from it and then insert it into another API.

**WorkFlow:** External Feed -> Parsing -> Insert into to Another API

Coding Part: 
Function Defined in a Parsing class.

```
 def parsed_items(self):
    self.get_response()
    items = self.soup.find_all('item')
    self.payload = []

    for item in items:
        self.payload.append({'title': item.find('title').text,
                        'description': item.find('description').text,
                        'status': '3'
                        }
                       )
    return self.payload
```

Function Defined in main class to get values of this function.

```
 for items in parser.parsed_items():
        response2 = requests.request('POST', settings.BASE_URL,
                                     json= (items['title'], items['description'], items['status']),
                                     headers=headers())
```

Sample of JSON:

```
{ Data: 
{
  "title": "ipsum",
  "description": "lorem"
}
{
  "title": "ipsum1",
  "description": "lorem1"
}
{
  "title": "ipsum2",
  "description": "lorem2"
}
{
  "title": "ipsum3",
  "description": "lorem3"
}
}
```

Error:

```
{"errors":[{"status":"400","source":"non_field_errors","detail":"Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got list."}]}
```

I need to know ?
Q1: What is the best way to handle such scenarios? Please refer any tutorial which can be helpful in this scenario.
Q2: How to retrieve list of values from payload ? Any example that you can refer ?
Q3: How can the list which is returned back by parse_item() be converted into dictionary and passed into request for value of json parameter.

I need to fetch these values of "title" and "description" from JSON and POST them in local API. (Note: Local API is authenticated successfully)

Comment: There are a at least a couple of syntax errors in your code. Please fix them. Also, try to stick to the standard 4 spaces for indentation in Python.

Comment: Also, you've left out the most important parts: what is the dictionary and what sort of list do you want from it?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Plz check now.

Comment: List of what values? "lorem, lorem1, lorem2..." or what? Like I said, we need to know your expected *output*. What will the list look like given your input?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga expected output is to insert value of fields ('title', 'description', 'status') from JSON feed into API(base_url) (via requests library). Let me know what else you need to know, to have a better understanding of the problem.